# Visual Studio: How to get the number days and hours from two DateTimePicker

Tags: vba, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

[image]

I need your help, I can't figure out what to do.

I have two DateTimePicker:

**DateTimePicker1** = which returns a date

**DateTimePicker2** - which returns a time

I would like to get the difference from the *current date & time* to those *two DateTimePicker's* to get the **number of days and hours**.

Comment: var diff = dtp1.Value.ToTimeOfDay - dtp2.Value.ToTimeOfDay

Comment: Visual Studio has nothing to do with the question. Which stack are you using? WPF? Winforms? ASP.NET? All of them have a control named DateTimePicker. IN all cases though values are retrieved through the `Value` property, not the `Text`. That `Value` is a `DateTime` value which has no format

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, the DateTimePicker1 is set to get just the date and the DateTimePicker2 to get the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dim combine As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value.**Date** + DateTimePicker2.Value.**TimeOfDay**

Dim currentDate As Date = Date.Now()

Dim timeDifference As TimeSpan = combine - currentDate

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. You can do the operations you describe as below though

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dpt1 = new DateTime(2019, 02, 15);
        DateTime dpt2 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 10, 30, 45);

        DateTime combined = new DateTime(dpt1.Year, dpt1.Month, dpt1.Day, dpt2.Hour, dpt2.Minute, dpt2.Second);
        var diff = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks - combined.Ticks);
        var hours = diff.Hour;
    }
```

I see an issue with what you are asking though. "I would like the difference from the current date & time to those two DateTimePicker's so I can get the total number of days and hours." Unfortunately you won't be able to extract the day differences since in the dpt2 you are only selected hours/minutes/seconds. The month/day/year field is essentially useless and unusable in the calculation.

If you want to specifically get the timespan difference you can easily do that with

```
TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - combined.Ticks);
```

Comment: the dpt2.Hour, dpt2.Minute, dpt2.Second doesn't work, gives me an error that it cannot be converted to int.

Comment: still need help any one?

Comment: The code I pasted compiled and ran fine in a new console app. You can subtract 2 datetimes with a - operator and the result will be a timespan.